# what does " $mark_state_id = $r['mark_state_id'] == 2 ? 1 : 2; " mean?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

what does `$mark_state_id = $r['mark_state_id'] == 2 ? 1 : 2;` mean ?

Friends, what is it doing above?

Comment: `$mark_state_id` becomes 2 unless `$r['mark_state_id']` is 2, in which case it becomes 1.

Comment: Seems like a toggle statement, though, so `$mark_state_id = 3 - $r['mark_state_id'];` should also work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is better written as (with brackets for clarity):

```
$mark_state_id = ($r['mark_state_id'] == 2 ? 1 : 2);
```

which means "If `$r['mark_state_id']` is equal to 2, then return 1, else return 2. Then `$mark_state_id` will take the returned value above. This is equivalent to:

```
$mark_state_id;
if($r['mark_state_id'] == 2){
   $mark_state_id = 1;
} else {
   $mark_state_id = 2;
}
```

It uses the [ternary operator](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/3/12/4/the-ternary-operator) as a shorthand for if/else.

Answer (score 0):

That is a ternary operator, what is says is: if `$r['mark_state_id']` = 2 then `$mark_state_id` = 1 else `$mark_state_id` = 2.

Which basically means this if/else statement:

```
if($r['mark_state_id'] == 2){
  $mark_state_id = 1;
} else {
  $mark_state_id = 2;
}
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: That is most likely the case

Comment: Same for all answers..

Comment: @Drakes what is `Serial downvoter`???

Comment: @Abdulla Replace downvoter with murderer, then it should become clear.

Answer (score 0):

> The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.

It will check `$r['mark_state_id'] == 2`. If it is `true` then it will assign `1` else `2`.
`$mark_state_id = $r['mark_state_id'] == 2 ? 1 : 2;` similar to -

```
if($r['mark_state_id'] == 2) {
    $mark_state_id = 1;
} else {
    $mark_state_id = 2;
}
```

[Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> The ternary operator is an expression, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of an expression. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is issued in later PHP versions.